# How to send data to selected mailId without using MFMailcomposer in ios

Tags: ios, sendmail, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send an array data through mail. I know it's possible through `MFMailcomposerViewController`.

But as per my requirement without using `MFMailcomposerViewController` how it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to or can't use `MFMailcomposerViewController` you should send the data to your server and have it create and send the e-mail.